# Symfony2: Get input value in functional testing

Tags: php, symfony, testing, functional-testing

I have this functional test (I'm just showing a fragment):

```
namespace Just\An\ExampleBundle\Tests\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ExampleControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
  public function testCrearTipus()
  {
    $client = static::createClient(array(), array(
            'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'login',
            'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'pa$$sword'
    ));
    $client->followRedirects();
    $url = '/admin/type/new';
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
    $token = $crawler->filter('input[name="name_of_form[_token]"]')->first()->getValue();
    .....
  }
}
```

I just cannot get the value of the input defined in my view as:

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what is the value you are getting if you `var_dump($token)`? Have you tried dumping the contents of `$client->getResponse()->getContent()` to a file and making sure it's as you expect?

Comment: `$client->getResponse()->getContent()`returns the expected HTML. I can't perform a `var_dump($token)`, because it throws an error when trying to get `$token` value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a button in your form you can try this instead.

```
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
    $buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('Save');

    $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();

    $token = $form->get('name_of_form[_token]')->getValue()
```

where Save is the text you have in your button

Comment: Will `getValue()` return the `value` attribute?

Comment: @OscarPérez yes in my case print $token returned 720c38eb36cddde999e67a0681ad78f373958322

Comment: do you know how can I get it in symfony3? It says `Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler::value()`, when I call `$form->get('poetry_form[author_autocomplete]')->getValue()`

Comment: okay, I found another way. I can get it by the crawler this way:
`$crawler->filter('input[id=poetry_form_author_autocomplete]')->attr('value');`

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use name selector,

```
   $appClient        = static::createClient();
   $requestCrawler   = $appClient->request('GET', $url;
   $tokenExtract     = $requestCrawler->filter('input[name="name_of_form[_token]"]')
                                    ->extract(array('value'));
   $csrfToken        = $tokenExtract[0];
```

Comment: It's good to be able to do it directly from crawler, without needing a form object!