# Why can't I get value-attribute of form input in functional test (Symfony 5.1)?

Tags: php, symfony, testing, symfony-forms, functional-testing

I am writing a functional test for a form in phpunit with the [DomCrawler Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#forms) in a Symfony 5.1 application. I read the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/17-tests.html#submitting-a-form-in-a-functional-test) as well as previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494784/symfony2-get-input-value-in-functional-testing) ([another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804753/symfony-4-functional-form-test-with-csrf-token-and-session)), but I can't get it to work.

The test should check:

- Login (works)
- Goto user overview (works)
- Click edit for first item in user list (works)
- Check if the data displayed in the form is correct (fails)

I am able to get all attributes of the form input, except for the value attribute. The url of the form edit page is `/user-action?user=2`.

My test looks like this:

```php
public function testIfDisplayedInfosAreCorrect() 
{ 
  $crawler = $this->client->clickLink('Edit'); // from user overview -> click edit
    
  // $crawler->getUri() returns "/user-action?user=2" at this point (which is fine)
  // $crawler->filter('#user_firstname')->attr('class') returns the class names of the form input
  // $crawler->filter('#user_firstname')->attr('value') returns null
    
  $form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')->form();
  $firstName = $form->get('user[firstname]')->getValue(); // returns null
  $this->assertSame("Admin", $firstName); // fails 
}
```

Why can't I get the value of the form element? I hope it's clear what I mean, please let me know otherwise.

Edit: Dumping all values with `$form->getValues();` also returns empty strings for all input fields.

Edit 2: The controller looks as following:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/user-action", name="app_user_action")
     */
    public function createAndEditUser(
        Request $request, 
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        SluggerInterface $slugger,
        UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder,
        UserHelper $userHelper): Response
    {   
        if(isset($_GET['user'])) {
            $user = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->find($_GET['user']);
            $email = $user->getEmail();
        } else {
            $user = new User();
            $email = '';
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
        {
            // parse input 
            // create or edit object
            // flush into db

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_users');
        }

        return $this->render('pages/user/action.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'email' => $email
        ]);
    }
```

Edit: Solution: Thanks to @DonCallisto's hint to use parameter converters, I removed the `$_GET` and used Symonfy's [annotations for routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-attributes-or-annotations), which solved the problem of not being able to have `if(isset($_GET['user']))` resolve to `true`.

Comment: Dumb question: have you interacted with the form? Have you preloaded something in it, that contains data? We cannot deduce too much for your question.

Comment: I hope the second edit answers your question. When I visit the page in a normal browser, there's no problem. But in the test, I can't read any value inside the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(isset($_GET['user']))` will return `false`, so you have not a single data inside the form.

BTW you should not use `$_GET`, but you can take advantage of [ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) and eventually pass user id inside URL.

Comment: That is the problem, thanks. I know I shouldn't use $_GET,  but why does `if(isset($_GET['user']))` return false?

Comment: @kwe 'cause you're visting the page without `user` parameter, I guess

Comment: as stated in the first code example, that's not true. Even if I send a direct request with `$client->request('GET', '/user-action?user=2');`, `if(isset($_GET['user']))` will return false.